# Exporting default value from a module in Typescript declaration file

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a declarations file `foo.d.ts`:

```
declare namespace foo {
  interface Bar {
    (): void;
  }
}

declare var foo: foo.Bar;
export default foo;
```

If I compile this:

```
import Foo from './foo';
Foo();
```

The resulting output is:

```
"use strict";
var foo_1 = require('./foo');
foo_1["default"]();
```

However this code won't run as `foo_1` is a function and has no property `default`. How can I get the output to be `foo_1()` instead of `foo_1["default"]()`?

Comment: have you configured a module in the tsconfig.json file? You probably shouldn't in your case.

Comment: No, this is intended to be a declarations file to accompany a library.

Comment: you should **never** have a `declare namespace foo {}` and a `declare var foo` in the same file. try renaming one of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
export = foo;
```

instead of `export default foo;` in your declaration file

and use `import require` when importing:

```
import Foo = require('./foo');
```

[Export assignment/import require](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require) is special syntax in typescript for dealing with node modules with exports like

```
module.exports = function someFunction() {}
```